# sqlite `pragma optimize`: what about running it in background thread/connection, on start?

Tags: sqlite, optimization

I'm writing website: in C++, as nginx module, uses SQLite. Website's uptime is normally huge. Let's also assume huge database, just to cover all ends from the start.

I want it fast, including instant start/stop.

If I run [`pragma optimize`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_optimize) on each connection close, as recommended, eventually it'll freeze thinking, and sysadmin along: why nginx has frozen? Kill it! And if I run `pragma optimize` every few hours on working connections (one connection per nginx worker thread), the ones occasionally thinking will be users.

Of course I'll issue [`pragma analyze_limit = 1000`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_analysis_limit) beforehand, but my inner perfectionist still complains. On `sqlite3_interrupt()` he complains even more.

So, I want to run background thread with separate connection and do all maintenance there, including `pragma optimize` every those few hours. It's a pretty typical pattern: in-application cron-like stuff.

**Questions:**

**-- 1 --** How much will I lose, compared to running `pragma optimize` before closing **real** working connections?

I will suppress [MASK bit 8](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_optimize) (auto-create indexes, not yet implemented) because I don't like someone doing so far-reaching decisions for me, not to mention doing it automatically. But beside that, will `optimize` at least still call `analyze` for all appropriate tables?

**-- 2 --** If I'll run `pragma optimize` in background thread, **will it block** DMLs executed by worker connections?

If not, it would be ideal: site would work fast from very start, even if sysadmin killed nginx during previous optimization; background thread will have enough time to do its work even without `pragma analyze_limit` -- on start and every few hours; and when all connections get closed on termination, chances their `pragma optimize` will be NOOP are about 100%.

**Thanks. :)**

Answer (score 0):

I was advised to periodically (e.g. after 100K queries) create new connection in worker threads, and move old connection to background thread for maintenance and closing.

As for my idea to run optimize in separate connection to work, bit 4 of `pragma optimize` MASK must be implemented.